# Try to understand the structure of sentence

Tags: word-usage, word-order

He thought Micheal wouldn't respond.

In the above sentence, "He" is the subject pronoun, "thought" is the main verb. What are the rest of the words playing role in the sentence?

Please help me to understand the sentence structure?

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> *He thought* [*Micheal wouldn't respond*].

The sentence consists of "He" as subject and the verb phrase "thought Micheal wouldn't respond" as the predicate.

The matrix verb is "thought", which has the bracketed subordinate content clause functioning as its complement.

It's called a content clause because, in this case, it simply expresses details, i.e. the content, of what "he" thought.

The content clause consists of "Michael" as subject and the verb phrase "wouldn't respond" as predicate, in which "wouldn't" is the matrix verb with "respond" as a subordinate clause functioning as its complement.

Comment: Thank you very much, much appreciated. It helps a lot.